# Mutual SSL using CA issued certificates

Tags: php, apache, authentication, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to find a fairly straight forward method to do mutual SSL between servers, using CA issued certificates.  Most of the information I've found involves issuing self-signed certs to clients, storing those certs, etc.  Is there a reliable method for doing 2 way SSL using existing CA issued certs?  *(I'm developing in a LAMP environment btw.)*

Answer (score 1):

The difference between self-signed and CA issued isn't much once the cert creation is done. In both cases you need to have the client pass the certificate during the SSL handshake and have the server validate the cert and use it to login the remote user.

When you go server-to-server, you treat the originating server as the client and the destination server as the server. Everything is then the same as going from a client machine to server machine. Depending on the exact authentication/authorization model you're using, you may need to create a "user" account on the destination server for the originating server which may seem odd to have a user account for a server, but it frequently simplifies the security model by not needing to special case a call from another server.

I'm not really a PHP expert but this looks like a [reasonable reference](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/ssl-client-certificates.htm) for LAMP mutual authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the article, looks pretty helpful.  It appears I had done everything correctly.  I must have missed something somewhere though.  I'll have to go back through everything again.

Comment: Configuration can be a hassle as it tends to look like either nothing worked or everything worked. Crank logging as high as you can while you're configuring it.